# How to recover a string that has been split by a regular expression in Java

Tags: java, expression

We know that `String.split(String regex)` returns a `String[]`. So, how can we recover a string by using the returned `String[]` and the regex (or needs more inputs)?

1. It seems like if the regex is a constant, say `\t`, we can recover the original string by appending the joint of each member of the `String[]` and the constant sequentially. However, what if the regex is sth. like `[AB]+` ?
2. If there is a all-around way(function) that can handle the above both cases ?

Comment: It looks like you have answered your question yourself. 'A*' can consume variety of substrings so you can't get it back accurately from regx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method present in JDK which can do this, but you can use the [Apache Commons Langs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) [StringUtls](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/) class , it will work

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author Himanshu Mishra
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String orignalStr = "AB:#:CD:#:EF";
        String[] orignalSplit = orignalStr.split(":#:");


        // Join all Strings in the Array into a Single String, separated by :#:

        System.out.println("Join Strings using separator " + StringUtils.join(orignalSplit, ":#:"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless the regex is a literal, and even then it's not 100% reliable.

The reason is the matched separators are discarded, so a non-literal regex, for example

```
 \s+ (any number if whitespace characters)
```

can not be reconstructed, because we don't know how many, and what type of, whitespace characters originally existed.

If the regex is a literal, you can simply rebuild the string by inserting the literal between the elements split, but not that *trailing* blanks as ignored, both of these inputs:

```
a,b,c
a,b,c,,,,,
```

when split with `","` both yield the same result of `[a, b, c]`, so even with a literal regex you can't confidently recreate the original input.

Comment: HI, Bohemian. Tks for your help. The reply is helpful on solving some question I had in mind. Thanks,:)